# Adding some error catching in jQuery in a case the user JSON response does not contain a an item

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a jQuery giving me a problem in implementing `if statement` with it. I am outputting an item called `city`, and if from the response its not available, I like to show: City Not Found.

This is what i have done:

```js
   

 $.get("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function(parseResponse) {
  if ($("#address") != null){
        $("#address").html("City: " + parseResponse.city);
        $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(parseResponse, null, 4));
    }
  else  {
        $("#city").html("City: Not Found");
    }
}, "jsonp");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<hr/>
<div id="ip"></div>
<div id="address"></div>
<hr/>Full response: <pre id="details"></pre>
```

> What am i doing wrong? Am trying to get city written out and when its not available, it shows `Not Found`

Comment: You'll have to be  clearer on what you're trying to check here, but `$("#address") != null` will **always** be true, a jQuery collection is never null.

Comment: @adeneo why did you remove your answer after marking the question so incorrect in one instance or the other?

Comment: You accepted the other answer, so I assumed mine was incorrect and removed it.

Comment: Well, such a ridiculous negative vote on the question. Forgetting my response/format call is json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `||`, you can use the trailing option instead of the initial option if the initial option is null, empty, etc.

```js
   

 $.get("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function(parseResponse) {
  if ($("#address") != null){
        $("#address").html("City: " + (parseResponse.city || "Not Found."));
        $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(parseResponse, null, 4));
    }
  else  {
        $("#city").html("City: Not Found");
    }
}, "jsonp");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<hr/>
<div id="ip"></div>
<div id="address"></div>
<hr/>Full response: <pre id="details"></pre>
```